# MySQL won't start

Tags: mysql

When I try to start MySQL I get:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

When I use sudo I get:

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Victorias-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
```

I am working with Mac OS X 10.7.  I installed MySQL through homebrew and I installed MySQL 5.5.20.

This is the .err file I am getting:

```
120513 22:30:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120513 22:30:03 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:03 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120513 22:30:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120513 22:30:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120513 22:30:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120513 22:30:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120513 22:30:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120513 22:30:03 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120513 22:30:03  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120513 22:30:04 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120513 22:30:04 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Victorias-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
120513 22:30:13 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120513 22:30:13 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:13 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120513 22:30:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120513 22:30:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120513 22:30:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120513 22:30:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120513 22:30:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120513 22:30:13 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120513 22:30:13  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120513 22:30:14 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120513 22:30:14 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Victorias-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
120513 22:30:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120513 22:30:24 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:24 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120513 22:30:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120513 22:30:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120513 22:30:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120513 22:30:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120513 22:30:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120513 22:30:24 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120513 22:30:24  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120513 22:30:25 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120513 22:30:25 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:25 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Victorias-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
120513 22:30:34 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120513 22:30:34 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:34 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120513 22:30:34 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120513 22:30:34 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120513 22:30:34 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120513 22:30:34 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120513 22:30:34 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120513 22:30:34 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120513 22:30:34  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120513 22:30:35 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120513 22:30:35 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:35 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Victorias-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
120513 22:30:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120513 22:30:44 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:44 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120513 22:30:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120513 22:30:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120513 22:30:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120513 22:30:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120513 22:30:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120513 22:30:44 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120513 22:30:44  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120513 22:30:45 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120513 22:30:45 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:45 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Victorias-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
120513 22:30:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120513 22:30:54 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:54 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120513 22:30:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120513 22:30:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120513 22:30:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120513 22:30:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120513 22:30:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120513 22:30:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120513 22:30:54  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120513 22:30:55 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120513 22:30:55 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
120513 22:30:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Victorias-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
120513 22:31:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120513 22:31:04 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120513 22:31:04 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120513 22:31:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120513 22:31:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120513 22:31:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120513 22:31:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120513 22:31:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120513 22:31:04 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120513 22:31:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
```

Comment: Could you add more information related to the environment you are trying to start mysql on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this pid file, make sure all the instances are stopped (kill any processes not going down), check nothing is listening the MySQL port 3306 (netstat should help) and try to start MySQL again.

Comment: I am getting the same error, but I don't see any pid files..

Comment: Easy way to kill any running mysqld processes is go to Activity Monitor and search for it, then hit Quit. Worked for me.