# Mysql command not found in OS X 10.7

Tags: mysql

I cant get my mysql to start  on os x 10.7.  It is located in `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

I get command not found when I type `mysql --version` in the terminal.

I tried this [can't access mysql from command line mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195418/cant-access-mysql-from-command-line-mac) but still get command not found.  I tried installing mysql with the dmg and i have tried to install it through homebrew and I cant get it to work.  When I try to start mysql with homebrew I get [MySQL won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576743/mysql-wont-start/10576831#10576831)

This is my `$PATH`:

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Victoria/bin:/usr/local//usr/local/mysql/bin/private/var/mysql/private/var/mysql/bin

Comment: Is the install directory in your PATH?

Comment: There are a number of things to check. Firstly follow the install instructions carefully that are provided with the DMG & cover all the relevant steps for OS X. There is a system prefs panel provided to start/stop mysql too. Additionally OSX is notorious for changing the location of mysql.sock - you will need to set it to /tmp/mysql.sock in my.cnf & php.ini - google that, there will be many guides

Comment: mysql --version will only work if you instruct BASH to have that shortcut command - this is detailed in the install read me

Comment: If you navigate to mysql folder 
    cd /usr/local/mysql/bin
& then issue the version command, it will work.
    ./mysql --version

Answer (score 438, accepted):

This is the problem with your $PATH:

`/usr/local//usr/local/mysql/bin/private/var/mysql/private/var/mysql/bin`.

`$PATH` is where the shell searches for command files. Folders to search in need to be separated with a colon. And so you want `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` in your path but instead it searches in `/usr/local//usr/local/mysql/bin/private/var/mysql/private/var/mysql/bin`, which probably doesn't exist.

Instead you want `${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

So do `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

If you want this to be run every time you open terminal put it in the file `.bash_profile`, which is run when Terminal opens.

Comment: now I am getting the error I was getting with homebrew ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: This means that the mysql socket is misplaced, which is a very different error. That is a problem with mysql, not your `$PATH`.

Comment: Do what the other answer said: Remove this pid file, make sure all the instances are stopped (kill any processes not going down), check nothing is listening the MySQL port 3306 (netstat should help) and try to start MySQL again.

Comment: I would recommend opening Activity Monitor and killing all instances of mysql

Comment: in which file i need to set path

Comment: My mysql binary wasn't in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

Comment: Works without parenthesis too. So, `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` will also do.

Comment: To automatically add the executable files from the current dir., i would suggest to add `export PATH=$PATH:.` (notice `.` after `:`), in to `.bash_profile`
so, no need to manually export every executable file

Comment: do export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin. this code worked for me

Comment: I noticed that I needed to issue the "export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin" command before the mysql command would start working.  In other words, I couldn't go to the bin folder and directly execute mysql.  Also, it seems /usr/local/mysql is the correct folder and not the other mysql-versionName folder next to it.  I realized this after launching  mySQL.prefPane and then seeing the configuration settings pointing to /user/local/mysql.

Comment: if this is not working for you, edit your **zshrc** file. `open -t ~/.zshrc`, `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/`, `source ~/.zshrc`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404895/10505343 for reference.

Answer (score 46):

One alternative way is creating soft link in `/usr/local/bin`

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

But if you need other executables like `mysqldump`, you will need to create soft link for them.

Comment: or `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql`

Answer (score 38):

If you installed MySQL Server and you still get

```
mysql -u root -p command not found
```

You're most likely experiencing this because you have an older mac version.

Try this:

in the home directory in terminal `open -t .bash_profile`

paste `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/` inside and save it

instead of writing `mysql -u root -p` paste the following in your terminal:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

**Or** use Alias instead of writing the full path

```
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

Enter your password. Now you're in.

Comment: Instead of writing full path use alias Eg:  alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Answer (score 35):

I faced the same issue, and finally i got a solution. Please go through with the below steps, if you are using MAMP.

1. Start MAMP or MAMP PRO
2. Start the server
3. Open Terminal (Applications -> Utilities)
4. Type in: (one line)
       /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot

This works for me.

Answer (score 31):

You have to set PATH for mysql in your `.bashrc` file using following:

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

But If you are using `oh my zsh` then you have to add path inside `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 11):

Your **PATH** might not setup. Go to terminal and type:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Essentially, this allows you to access mysql from anywhere.

Type `cat .bash_profile` to check the PATH has been setup.

Check **mysql** version now: `mysql --version`

If this still doesn't work, close the terminal and reopen. Check the version now, it should work. Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

Use these two commands in your terminal

```
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
mysql --user=root -p
```

Then it will ask you to enter password of your user pc

Enter password:

Answer (score 8):

I have tried a lot of the suggestions on SO but this is the one that actually worked for me:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql/bin > /etc/paths.d/mysql'
```

then you type

```
mysql
```

It will prompt you to enter your password.

Comment: I haven't used the new Mac version, my mac died :( so I cannot test it anymore

Answer (score 4):

If you are using terminal, you will want to add the following to `./bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

If you are using zsh, you will want to add the line to your `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines in bash_profile:

```
alias startmysql='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start'
alias stopmysql='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop'
```

and save the bash_profile.

Now, in the terminal start and stop the mysql server using the following commands:

```
startmysql //to start mysql server
```

and

```
stopmysql //to stop mysql server
```

Answer (score 3):

With MAMP

1. Locate mysql usually at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
2. sudo vi /etc/paths
3. Add this path to file /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
4. :wq (Save and quit file)
5. Close Terminal windows
6. Reopen Terminal and type mysql and it should work

Comment: it worked for me. In my case mysql8 path was /usr/local/mysql/bin

Answer (score 2):

I installed MAMP and phpmyadmin was working.

But cannot find /usr/local/bin/mysql

This fixed it

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

Comment: its creating a symlink . To remove it try this https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-symbolic-links-in-linux/

Answer (score 2):

in terminal do:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

And add this line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

and the type this in terminal:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [password]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'll help someone else. None of the above answers worked for Catalina. Finally, this solved the problem

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/$(whoami)/.bash_profile`

Of course, you have to change for the version of mysql you have installed

Answer (score 0):

May be i will help out some of you that  even though if you are unable to open mysql from terminal after trying changing path in .bash_profile

then you always found the error "MYSQL not found"
hence you can use the following command directly it will ask for your password and sql bash is opened

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after installing **mariadb** via **HomeBrew**, `brew doctor` suggested to run `brew link mariadb` - which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are using zsh instead of bash then you have to enter the above mentioned commands in .zshenv instead of .bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

after appending mysql path to your environment variables:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

you may need to reload your environment variables with one of these commands:

```
source ~/.bashrc  # If you use Default Bash

source ~/.zshrc   # If you use Oh-My-Zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same to run mysql on MacOS terminal but it was showing an error.

Then I tried this

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
mysql -u -root -p
```

Then enter your MySQL password in prompt

Answer (score 0):

ls -a

if you dont have .bash_profile file just create it

touch .bash_profile

if you have just open

open -t .bash_profile

add this line

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin

then in terminal

source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).