# mysql syntax error near expected new line in terminal mac

Tags: mysql, syntax, terminal

I am running the following command as given on web to connect the mysql data base but it gives syntax error new line expected here is the command i am entering.

```
mysql -<hivelettest.c0e9graawyhr.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com  -p 3306  -u <user> -p <pass>
```

Comment: Are those real logins? Replace them with fakes if so.

Comment: Better: just change your password

Answer (score -1):

The `<>` parts of the command were given to show where the username and password should go. They shouldn't be in the command:

```
mysql -hmydbserver.co.uk  -P3306  -u username -pmypassword
```

Comment: there is no white space between the -p and the password

Comment: @AijazAli That means that the MySQL command isn't found, I'm not familiar with Macs but this link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found

Answer (score -1):

Try this, and make sure that there is no space between -u or -p. And if you are using `PORT` you need to write it differently. The password parameter must then be `--password=`

```
mysql -hmydbserver.co.uk  -P 3306  -uUsername --password=yourpassword
```

Since `3306` is the standard one you could leave it out, then you can write it like this.

```
mysql -hmydbserver.co.uk  -uUsername -pYourpassword
```

If you want to pass with a command, do it like this.

```
 mysql -hmydbserver.co.uk  -P 3306  -uUsername --password=yourpassword nameofdatabase 
 -e "SELECT * FROM tablename"
```

Comment: @AijazAli Is the `mysql` program in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @Barmar how to check mysql is in path

Comment: `echo $PATH` and look at the list of directories to see if it includes the directory that contains mysql?

Comment: but i have xamp installed on my mac

Comment: Its requesting a command to be executed. Did you try the latest change? mysql -hmydbserver.co.uk  -P 3306  -uUsername --password=yourpassword nameofdatabase 
 -e "SELECT * FROM thenameofanytable" - Does this still give you "no command found?"

Comment: CAn you run this and tell me the error message? mysql -hmydbserver.co.uk -P 3306 -uUsername --password=yourpassword nameofdatabase -e "'SELECT * FROM thenameofanytable". It should give a syntax error