# Can't start mysql (5.7.10) from command line OSX Yosemite (10.10.5)

Tags: mysql

When I start mysql using `System Preferences>MySQL>StartMySQLServer`, then I can do this:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64/bin$ ./mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: <password shown me during installation>
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.7.10

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my new password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

And I can see the mysql process created by `System Preferences>MySQL>StartMySQLServer`:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons$ ps -e | grep mysql
 1735 ??         0:00.31 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
 1743 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql
/Library/LaunchDaemons$
```

But after stopping the server using `System Preferences>MySQL`, I am unable to start the mysql server using the command line (following the instructions in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-launchd.html)):

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64/bin$ sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64/bin$ ./mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: <new password>
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

There's no mysql process:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64/bin$ ps -e | grep mysql
 1920 ttys001    0:00.00 grep mysql
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64/bin$
```

How are you supposed to start the mysql server from the command line?

Comment: Take a look at mysqld's error log

Comment: @pvg, `find . -name *log*` doesn't reveal any such file.

Comment: I didn't say 'look at some file with name that contains the substring log'. Try /usr/local/mysql/data/, look for files ending in *.err.

Comment: `cd: data: Permission denied` and `drwxr-x---  14 _mysql  _mysql     476 Jan 10 11:51 data`

Comment: you might want to sudo first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the mysql server first before you can connect. I think you you must start mysqld daemon but i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

I use following command on terminal to start mysql:

```
mysql.server start
```

Give it a try.

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: its version is 5.6.26

Comment: What output do you get for `$ which mysql.server`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/mysql.server

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't exist for me, hence the error message.  The mysql 5.7 docs do not mention that method for starting the server.

Comment: it means you need to redefine its path, check this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found-in-os-x-10-7)

Comment: You can't specify a path to a non existent file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100310/discussion-between-aamir-and-7stud).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer you want is:

1.first, add your mysql path to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Save it and open a new terminal.

2.Then, you can start/stop/restart mysql by,(you can also choose to start it from the "mysql" in "system preferences" or to forget it):

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

3.After you start, use command "mysql" at your will~