# How to fix "command not found: mysql" in Zsh

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, zsh

I want to use MySQL with my Rails application.

After successfully installing the package and seeing the option to start and stop the server from the Preference Pane, if I execute

```
mysql --version
```

I get an error from zsh:

```
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

I understand that this has something to do with my `$PATH` variable and if I display my `$PATH` I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/bin
```

How do I resolve this error to get Mysql up and running?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This was a problem within my configuration and `$PATH` variable. I followed the "[How to install MySQL on Mac OS X El Capitan](http://wpguru.co.uk/2015/11/how-to-install-mysql-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/)" tutorial to resolve this.

In my terminal, I opened up the configuration by running `vi ~/.zshrc`, then located the line to export my PATH

```
export PATH="..."
```

and appended

```
:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

to it which resolved my issue.

Comment: do not forget to relaunch terminal :)

Answer (score 101):

You  paste this line to append the path to MySQL to your environment variables:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Then reload your environment variables with one of the following commands:

```
source ~/.zshrc   # If you use Oh-My-Zsh
source ~/.bashrc  # If you use Default Bash
```

Comment: I ran "source ~/.zshrc" on my VS code integrated terminal trying to fix my problem, which was the same as the question that was asked, and not just it didn't fix, but now my VS Code terminal won't stay open. When I open it or click open new terminal, it opens for a second but then it closes. Do you know what might be the cause?

Answer (score 77):

On the latest MacOS, Catalina, I used this open the zsh config and edit:

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

and added

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

then ran

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

to make it work

Reopen a teminal and run `mysql -u root -p`, input the password and you can log into your MySQL account.

Answer (score 46):

On MacOs Catalina, open a terminal and run:

```
 sudo nano /etc/paths
```

And add to end of file:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Save the changes and quit, then reload the terminal.

Open a new terminal and run:

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 29):

For my MacOS Catalina system I tried everything above, but it didn't work. Input the code in your terminal:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

Thanks go to the "[How to Install MySQL on MacOS Big Sur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kijzRVw8eUQ)" video.

It worked also for MacOS Big Sur with an ARM processor.

Comment: Excellent answer!  
If everybody agrees the issue is on the path, no need to make a lot of changes, just use the correct path :)

Answer (score 8):

In my case those steps helped:

1. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/bin`
2. `mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal run:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/bin:$PATH
```

Then, if you run:

```
mysql
```

It should return:

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Run:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It should ask for your password and then be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This looks right, although it doesn't work right

`export VOLTA_HOME="$HOME/.volta" export PATH="$VOLTA_HOME/bin:$PATH" export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/bin:$PATH`

I have to manually run `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/` to get mysql to work..

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you adding the line to your `.zshrc`?