# MYSQL (Mac) - Could not connect, server may not be running

Tags: mysql, macos

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 54
```

I'm trying to create a connection on 127.0.0.1 port: 3306 through mysql workbench, but it is saying that no connection is established and gave me the following response above. I checked MySql and it says that I have an active instance of: MySQL 8.0.21 with a green circle. However, everytime I try to click "Stop MySql Server" to restart the connection, it asks me for my password and then does nothing. I'm not sure what's going on.

I've also tried to test my connection under "Configure Local Management" and received the following errors:

```
Could not connect to MySQL server:
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306
You may continue if the server is simply not running.
```

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling both mysql and workbench to no avail, as it seems to remember the connections I made before uninstalling.

Comment: what method did you use to install MySQL on your mac?

Comment: @finiteloop MYSQL Community Server > macOS 10.15 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive

Comment: is it possible you have it running with brew or something at the same time?

Comment: @finiteloop I'm not sure I tried  brew services stop mysql     on my home directory and it says Error: Service `mysql` is not started. I also tried mysql --version in my home directory and it says zsh: command not found

Comment: And the dmg installed correctly you said already and it looks like it is running OK?  Do any of the suggestions here help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858052/zsh-command-not-found-mysql

Comment: @finiteloop I tried one suggestion there and now when I do mysql --version it gives me: 
mysql  Ver 8.0.21 for macos10.15 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL).  But it is still saying that I am unable to connect 127.0.0.1:3306 and I still can't stop the connection through MySql