# zsh: command not found: mysql answered

Tags: sql, zsh

Kept getting this error every time I tried to start SQL on Mac

zsh: command not found: mysql
➜  u-develop-it git:(main) ✗

Comment: Answer is here: [zsh: command not found: mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858052/zsh-command-not-found-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

For zsh: command not found: mysql

GO TO DIRECTORY OF PROJECT

Try:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/"
```

Then enter

```
mysql -u root -p
```

you will then be prompted for SQL password

Or All toegther

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```