# bash: mysql: command not found CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, linux

```
bash: mysql: command not found
```

I have MySQL running in my centos but i cant access it using bash

```
270:03 /opt/rh/rh-mysql80/root/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/opt/rh/rh-mysql80/root/usr
```

```
whereis mysql
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib64/mysql /usr/share/mysql
```

How do I fix that? Any pointers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found-in-os-x-10-7
Similar Question